# How to encrypt and decrypt messages in laravel?

Tags: laravel, encryption, messaging

I want to work on a project where users can send messages to others users that are subscribe to their channels.

I want to ask if it's very necessary to encrypt the messages before storing them in the database? Although some messages may contain some sensitive information.

If yes, how do I go about encrypting the message in laravel and also decrypting it when showing it to the end user?

Comment: First of all, opinion based questions are not allowed on SO. If you want us to help you with encrypting/decrypting, do some research, give it a try, and if you get stuck, ask a question here with your code included. In that case we will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString('Hello world.');
$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can check Laravel's [encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption) methods.

```
Crypt::encryptString('<string>')
Crypt::decryptString($encryptedValue)
```